# Android: Search Query in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently working on an Android project backed by FIREBASE. When I perform querying similar to select statement in SQL, it does not give me the intended result.

My FIREBASE database looks like this:

[image]

The code I've used is as follows:

```
 ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("DiscussionForumPosts");
    ref.orderByChild("discussionName").equalTo(discussion_name_from_bundle)
    .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            DiscussionPostReadModel model = dataSnapshot.getValue(DiscussionPostReadModel.class);
        }
      //other predefined methods
 }
```

`discussion_name_bundle` is a string variable that I get from the previous activity.

My `DiscussionPostReadModel.java` looks like this:

```
public class DiscussionPostReadModel {
public String discussionName, discussionMessage, userName;

public DiscussionPostReadModel(){}

public DiscussionPostReadModel(String discussionName, String discussionMessage,  String userName){
    this.discussionName = discussionName;
    this.discussionMessage = discussionMessage;
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getDiscussionName(){
    return discussionName;
}
public String getDiscussionMessage(){
    return discussionMessage;
}
public String getUserName(){
    return userName;
}
}
```

I actually need the system to fetch only the nodes whose **discussionName** equals the variable `discussion_name_from_bundle`. instead, it returns to me all the children found in **discussionForumPost**  in the FIREBASE database.

Kindly help me do the functionality of retrieving only the children which satisfies the equality condition. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To only retrieve one result you need to also use the limitToFirst(wantedNumberOfResults) method.

You would implement it like this:

```
  ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("DiscussionForumPosts");
            ref.orderByChild("discussionName").equalTo(DiscussionForumPosts).limitToFirst(1).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        DiscussionPostReadModel model = dataSnapshot.getValue(DiscussionPostReadModel.class);
    }
  //other predefined methods
 }
```